# Calling child's viewmodel method from main Viewmodel

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I see in many posts that communications between viewmodels should be done using a messenger bus.

What I wonder is, is it considered bad to simply execute a child vm method from the main vm?

Suppose having a view with a TabControl, where each TabItem is a child viewmodel.

When I close my application, I need to store my settings calling a SaveSettings() child vm method.

I need to know if it's a bad code, and in case why.

```
main view
-> closingEvent
  -> call MainVM SaveAllSettings()
     -> for (ChildVM childVM in allTabs)
       --> childVM.SaveSettings() (public method)
```

Comment: Look into the event aggregator, and do something like EventAggregator.GetEvent<SaveEvent>.Publish(new SaveEvent()), and then have each view model have a subsriber, like EventAggregator.GetEvent<SaveEvent>.Subsribe(//some save event here)

Answer (score 2):

If your objects are already coupled to each other, i.e. if a parent view model already has a strong reference a child view model, there is no need to use a messenger or an event aggregator to communicate between them. Then you can (or rather should) call any methods of the child directly.

There are certainly cases where these kind of parent/child relationsships exist and it's not necessarily a bad thing or a sign of poor design. It all depends on the relationsships of your objects really.